# why won't this style.display work?

Tags: javascript, html

Why won't this work? It should check the element for `display` css style.

```
if (byId("annonsera_price").style.display=='inline' || byId("annonsera_price").style.display=='block'){
alert ("Hello");
}

function byId(x){
        return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

update2:

```
<input style="width:100px;" type="text" name="annonsera_price" id="annonsera_price">
```

I haven't set it with css either!

Comment: Btw, what doesn't work is that the alert box isn't shown, even though the display is actually set to 'block'!

Comment: Does byId("annonsera_price").style.display returns "block"?

Comment: no, it returns a blank alert box!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try alerting just the style.display and see what it contains:

```
var el = document.getElementById("annonsera_price");
alert(el.style.display);
```

`style` only references what is in the style attribute (or set through JS on the style property). It's possible that the display is set through the class, and therefore `el.style.display` won't show anything.

[**Update**]:Given the update, the reason no alert happens is because `style.display` will be "", not "inline" or "block".  It won't be "inline" or "block" until you set it to something, either in the `style` attribute or by setting `.style.display`.

Comment: You can use it in an if statement, that's why I say you need to tell us what it IS returning. If I set up my own element, your code will work for me.  We need to find out what the elements contain that you are dealing with.

Comment: I was wrong, I haven't set it with css at all... check update

Comment: The alerting returns a blank alert-box... No value!

Comment: and it returns a blank alert box when alert(style.display) of the element

Comment: That is correct.  `style.display` **will** be blank, until you set it to something.  Just because it has a default behavior, doesn't mean the `style.display` holds a default value.  A blank value just causes it to use its default behavior.

Answer (score 5):

If the style is set via CSS or is a default style, you need to get the computed style of the element:

```
var el    = document.getElementById("annonsera_price");

// currentStyle for IE, getComputedStyle for standards-compliant browsers
var style = el.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(el);

if (style.display == "inline" || style.display == "block")
    alert("Hello");
```

Comment: That's interesting. I always use tools like FireBug or IEDevtoolbar to find this out but it's always nice to know how to it through code