# Why do I have to click the button twice in order to make text appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-manipulation

I have two buttons that display and hide text when clicked using vanilla JavaScript. Only when the page is first loaded is when you have to click on the button twice. Otherwise, it works without having to click the second time. Why is this? I'm fairly new to programming and would love an explanation. I have tried to search for answers to guide me but I haven't found anything that has helped yet.

```js
var $ = function (id) {
 "use strict";
 return window.document.getElementById(id);
};

function hideShowCommuniTea() {
 "use strict";
 if ($('communiteaText').style.display === 'none') {
  $('communiteaText').style.display = 'block';

 } else {
  $('communiteaText').style.display = 'none';

 }
}

function hideShowBenefits() {
 "use strict";
 if ($('moreBenefits').style.display === 'none') {
  $('moreBenefits').style.display = 'block';
 } else {
  $('moreBenefits').style.display = 'none';

 }
}


//HANDLES ALL EVENT LISTENERS
function init() {
 "use strict";
 $('benefitsButton').addEventListener('click', hideShowBenefits);
 $('communitea').addEventListener('click', hideShowCommuniTea);

}
window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
nav{
  background-color: teal;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;

  
}
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  
}
a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
 color: hotpink;
}
header{
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-top: 3px solid #B0FFB0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #B0FFB0;

}
h1{
color: white;
}
section{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

article{
  width: 47%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  
}
article p{
   line-height: 2em;
}
button{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#moreBenefits, #communiteaText{
 display: none;
}
footer{
  clear: both;
  background-color: teal;
  height: 50px;

}
footer p{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
</head>

<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/shop.html">Shop</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <header>
  <h1>Welcome to the Tea Shop!</h1>
 </header>
 <section>
  <article>
   <h2>Benefits of Tea</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <button id="benefitsButton">Full Benefits</button>
   <p id="moreBenefits">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
   <h2>Why Choose Us</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   <button id="communitea">CommuniTea</button>
   <p id="communiteaText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </article>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2019 - All Rights Researved.</p>
 </footer>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: simple debugging will tell you why: `console.log($('moreBenefits').style.display)`

Comment: if you use class , it might work better (toggle it) https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @G-Cyr there is no jQuery here.

Comment: @epascarello oups `$('moreBenefits').style.display = 'block';` confused me, my bad . A good practice is to set class instead style on the fly . inititate first the class inside HTML , so no need to run twice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298813/why-wont-this-style-display-work